# How to access root on HerokuApp to use wget command

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, bigbluebutton, heroku-api

I  would like to install this

https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/install.html

On my Heroku App. There is also shell script to make the installation very easy.

https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install.

I managed to downgrade my herokuapp stack to 16. but i can't see a way to execute this shell command

`wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -w -v xenial-22 -a -w`

I'm Willing to pay an expert to help with this.

Comment: Heroku disallows root access on their dyno. Maybe it is possible by hosting a docker container on Heroku I haven't dabbed in that.

Comment: Do you have source of how to install such app on Docker container on Heroku. Thanks for taking time.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

First try to build a Docker image and execute the docker container without Heroku, mayble also upload the docker image on Docker Hub. Then try to get it to work on Heroku.

Comment: ok.we will try to do that. THanks Tin